# BeautifulSoup, retrieve the text of all child's <a> tag of <td>'s tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to retrieve the text of all `<a>` tags that are within `<td>` tags in my page.

Here is a piece of the Html source code,

```
        <td style="overflow:hidden;">
            <a href="https://random.com">
                Hello, what's up...                    </a>
        </td>

        <td style="overflow:hidden;">
            <a href="https://random2.com">
                Hola, como esta ?                    </a>
        </td>
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for td_tag in soup.find_all('td'):

    print td_tag.a.string
```

But I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because not every `td` on your page has an `a` child element. If there is no `a` child element, `td_tag.a` would be `None`.

The easiest way to fit the requirement would be to use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('td a'):
    print(a.get_text())
```

where `td a` would match all `a` elements that have `td` parent elements.

You may also go for a direct parent-child relationship check using `td > a`.